# EWS NullReferenceException when using service.FindItems

Tags: c#, web-services, exchangewebservices

I'm using EWS 2.2.0 to read emails from the exchange server.

```
 ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
 service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("address", "password");
 service.TraceEnabled = true;
 service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
 service.AutodiscoverUrl("mailAddress", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
 EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
 FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(1));
```

The exception is thrown at `service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(1));`

The stack trace:

```
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.WrapStream(Stream responseStream, String contentEncoding)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetResponseStream(IEwsHttpWebResponse response)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(IEwsHttpWebResponse response)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.InternalExecute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems[TItem](IEnumerable`1 parentFolderIds, SearchFilter searchFilter, String queryString, ViewBase view, Grouping groupBy, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandlingMode)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems(FolderId parentFolderId, SearchFilter searchFilter, ViewBase view)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName parentFolderName, ViewBase view)
```

I checked EWS API on Github #248 should fix the error, but the error is still there.

By the way, if I try to create an email and using `email.Send()`, the same exception happened.

There are few questions related to the same problem. Adding breakpoints and step through is not useful. Please help.